# Laravel how to update in Table using LaravelBatch(github)

Tags: laravel, github, eloquent

> Problem is when i press button **Update** then wanna use Bulk update.

**I tried this**

```
foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
        Choice::updateOrCreate([
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'time'  => $time,
            'topic_id' => $key,
            'question_number' => $value,
        ]);
    }
```

**This is example of [LaravelBatch](https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch)**

```
$table = 'users';
$value = [
[
     'id' => 1,
     'status' => 'active',
     'nickname' => 'Mohammad'
] ,
[
     'id' => 5,
     'status' => 'deactive',
     'nickname' => 'Ghanbari'
] ,
];
$index = 'id';
Batch::update($table, $value, $index);
```

**My View**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('choices.store') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
.................
<tbody>
    @foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->title }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->total }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
            <input class="form-control" value="0" type="number" onblur="tiin();" 
                   min="0" max="{{ $duplicate->total }}" step="1" 
                   name="number[{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}]"></input>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Шинэчлэх</a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
    <br /><button class="button btn btn-danger" type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

[image: This is it]

**Tried this too**

```
foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
            $table = 'choices';
            $value = ['topic_id' => $key, 'question_number' => $value, 'time' => $time ];
            $index = 'id';
        }
Batch::update($table, $value, $index);
```

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Batch' not found

but i already added important things in config/app.php

Comment: `topic_id` is your index key?

Comment: Have you run composer dump-autoload

Comment: Yes i have and didn't see that LaravelBatch.@DsRaj

Comment: Yes it is. @dekts

Answer (score 0):

use

```
use Mavinoo\LaravelBatch\LaravelBatchFacade;
```

at the top of the file.

Or use `\` befor batch if you have created an alias in your `app.php`

```
 \Batch::update($table, $value, $index);
```

Hope this helps.